# How can I run the 2 rails projects with the certificate file of main domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, subdomain, unicorn

I have the **SSL certificate file** of the main domain - **example.com**

Currently, I am running the one Rails App on **AWS EC2** using **Rails + Unicorn + Nginx**.

This is my **Nginx** config file which works.

```
upstream app_site {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/project/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /home/ubuntu/project/public;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/project/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/project/shared/log/nginx.error.log;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_site;
            break; 
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/public;
        try_files $uri @app;
        expires 1y; 
        add_header Cache-Control public; 

        add_header ETag ""; 
        break; 
     } 

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I am going to run one rails project more with **subdomain** - **https://app.example.com**

I have updated the **Nginx** file.

```
upstream app_site {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/project/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
upstream app2_site {
    server unix:/home/ubuntu/project2/shared/sockets/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
}
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /home/ubuntu/project/public;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/project/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/project/shared/log/nginx.error.log;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_site;
            break; 
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project/public;
        try_files $uri @app;
        expires 1y; 
        add_header Cache-Control public; 

        add_header ETag ""; 
        break; 
     } 

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name app.example.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/SSL/example.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    root /home/ubuntu/project2/public;
    access_log /home/ubuntu/project2/shared/log/nginx.access.log;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/project2/shared/log/nginx.error.log;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @app;
    location @app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app2_site;
            break; 
        }
    }

    location ~ ^/assets/ {
        root /home/ubuntu/project2/public;
        try_files $uri @app;
        expires 1y; 
        add_header Cache-Control public; 

        add_header ETag ""; 
        break; 
     } 

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

But **https://example.com** works properly but **https://app.example.com** doesn't work.

Anyone can help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it wildcard certificate? `*.example.com`

Comment: Hi @NemanjaK, sorry for the late reply. Yes. it is a wildcard certificate.

Comment: No problem. Are you sure the second project is working correctly?

Comment: Hi @NeK, yes. The issue was that that was not a wildcard certificate. I fixed it.
But the subdomain redirects to the main domain.